# Minimal ROS installation

Tags: roscore

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I'm working on a project for UDOO based robot and I would like to take advantages of ROS features.

I followed the tutorial on wiki.ros.org for UDOO.

When I have to choose which package install I choose ros-hydro-ros since I want a minimal installation
(other packages will be installed when needed).

I was surprised when list the content of /opt/ros/hydro/bin since roscore is not there!

So my question is: which package contains roscore?
More general: which packages are need to run ros  and develop basic packages (only message publish and receiver)?

Thanks for support
Alessandro

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/187719/minimal-ros-installation/) by [afranceson](https://answers.ros.org/users/19838/afranceson/) on ROS Answers with karma: 497 on 2014-07-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> So my question is: which package contains roscore?

```
$ source /opt/ros/hydro/setup.bash
$ dpkg -S `which roscore`
ros-hydro-roslaunch: /opt/ros/hydro/bin/roscore
```

At least, on Ubuntu Precise, x86.

But I'm surprised that `ros-hydro-ros` does not include that.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2014-07-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [afranceson](https://answers.ros.org/users/19838/afranceson/) on 2014-07-25**:
It works, thanks for your suggestion!

Ale